# Authentication with JWT how to force Angular App to refresh

Tags: angularjs, passport.js, jwt, mean

I am building a MEAN Stack App, with, doing Authentication with JWT and Passport, I am able to save the token on Local Storage on Login and remove it on Logout, this works perfect, but how the state of the Angular App does not update the state when the user logs in.
The only way to update the state is making a manual refresh.
I have tried `state.reload();`, `$state.go('.', {}, { reload: true });` and pretty much everything out there, the only thing that works is `$window.location.href = '/';`, but this makes no sense since I want to use ui-router state.
Is there away to force a Digest cycle or something that will update the state?

This is a snippet of the code that I have:

```
vm.doLogin = function() {
  vm.formError = '';
  authentication
    .login(vm.credentials)
    .error(function(err) {
      vm.formError = err.message;
    })
    .then(function() {
      $state.go('.', {}, { reload: true });
    });
};
```

I will really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `$state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});`
 Or you can go with **$route.reload();** which reinitializes your controller

```
var currentPageTemplate = $route.current.templateUrl;
$templateCache.remove(currentPageTemplate);
$route.reload();
```

Templates are cached.If this is the way you want to follow, then you need to remove the template from the $templateCache before you call reload.

The other option is to use cache-view=false in the view where you get to after you log in, if you are having problem to maintain the dynamic state in that particular view.

```
$window.location.reload(); //reinitializes the controller as well as the services however, forcing the hard reload is bad.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"home" is my abstract state which will host my modules.
"module1"&"module2" are two modules within "home"

 State definitions as follows.

    $stateProvider.state('login', {
            url: "/login",
           templateUrl: "app/login/login.html",
             controller: 'LoginController'
           })
.state('home', {
            url: "/home",
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: "<div ui-view></div>"
           })
        .state('home.module1', {
                 url: "/module1home",
                 templateUrl: "app/module1/module1.home.html",
                 controller: 'Module1HomeController'

             })

             .state('home.module2', {
                 url: "/module2home",
                 templateUrl: "app/module2/module2.home.html",
                 controller: 'Module2HomeController'

             });

 After successful login use the below code to navigate to "/home/module1home"(which ever default state's url) which in turn trigger the state.

 $location.path('/home/module1home');
```